# How res.redirect() work?Is it is used to redirect to a route or to a View in 'views' folder?

Tags: node.js

I want to redirect admin to the dashboard which is under`(views/admin/dashboard)` after he login successfully.How can I redirect him to dashboard while the current URL is 'http://localhost:3030/auth/login'.
I have read in docs about `res.redirect()` and know what is an absolute and relative path. But still not able to reach the dashboard.

I have tried all options like passing both relative and absolute path but it is not working.
relative path `"res.redirect('../admin/dashboard')"` that I have tried.

Comment: You would pass in the url to `res.redirect()`. For example, if the url for the dashboard is http://localhost:3030/dashboard, you can do `res.redirect(‘/dashboard’)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `req.baseurl` for redirection purpose in the express. Here is the simplest example that you can try.

```
app.get('/singup', function(req, res){
  res.send("please create account");
 });
app.get('/status', function(req,res){
// check if user have account or not redirect accordingly
res.redirect(req.baseUrl + '/singup');
});
app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res){
 res.send("Welcome you login succesfully");
});
app.get('/login', function(req, res){
 // redirect to /dashboard in current router after login verified 
 res.redirect(req.baseUrl + '/dashboard');
});
```

Comment: Thank u very much.I did not have tried solution you provided.But your answer cleared my point.